# JDBC creating procedure throws MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am trying to run an SQL script in a java application using JDBC and HikariConfig.

```
CREATE TABLE table_AA(NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);


CREATE PROCEDURE `ASDF`()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM table_AA;
end;
```

Code in java used to run the SQL code

```
package YourPluginName.Storage;

import YourPluginName.Main.Main;
import org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;    
public class DatabaseSetup {

        public static boolean setupTables() {

            try (Connection connection = SQLPool.getConnection()) {
                System.out.println("Connection established......");
                //Initialize the script runner
                ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(connection);
                //Creating a reader object
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Main.getPlugin().getClass().getResourceAsStream("/SQL_SETUP.sql")));
                //Running the script
                sr.runScript(reader);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return true;
        }

        private static File getFile(String fileName) {
            ClassLoader classLoader = Main.getPlugin().getClass().getClassLoader();
            File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
            return file;
        }
    }
```

And for reference the definition of SQLPool

```
package YourPluginName.Storage;

import YourPluginName.Main.Main;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class SQLPool {

    private static String host, username, database, password;
    private static int port;

    private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    private static HikariDataSource ds;

    static {
        try {
            FileConfiguration config = Main.getPlugin().getConfig();
            host = config.getString("host");
            port = config.getInt("port");
            database = config.getString("database");
            username = config.getString("username");
            password = config.getString("password");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Main.log().error("Could not load MySQL data from configuration file");
        }

        if (host == null) {
            Main.log().error("Host is null");
        }
        if (database == null) {
            Main.log().error("Database is null");
        }
        if (username == null) {
            Main.log().error("Username is null");
        }
        if (password == null) {
            Main.log().error("Password is null");
        }

        Main.log().log("Connecting to HOST: " + host + " on PORT: " + port + " FOR DATABASE " + database);
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database + "");
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        config.addDataSourceProperty("autoReconnect", true);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", true);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", 250);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", 2048);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", true);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cacheResultSetMetadata", true);
        config.setConnectionTimeout(3000);

        ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
        Main.log().log("DATABASE IS WORKING!");
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return ds.getConnection();
    }

    public static boolean sendCommand(ThrowingConsumer<Connection> function) {
        try (Connection connection = SQLPool.getConnection()) {
            try {
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                function.acceptThrows(connection);
                connection.commit();
                Main.log().log("Successful database transaction");
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Main.log().error("Rolled back database transaction");
                connection.rollback();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Main.log().error("Unsuccessful database transaction");
        return false;
    }

    public static void close() {
        try {
            ds.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Main.log().error("A SQLException was caught" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, the creation of the table works fine, but the creation of the procedure throws a weird error. I tried finding similar problems online but to no avail.

```
Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: For security reasons, JDBC drivers generally don't allow executing multiple SQL statements in a single call. You need to call `execute(sql)` twice, once for the `CREATE TABLE` statement, and once for the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement. You can using batching to reduce the number of turnarounds to the database server.

Comment: So, is there any way I can restructure my SQL file to accommodate this?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do that.

Comment: Could you direct me to resources on how to do that? I have searched but haven't found any.

Comment: Well, the easiest is to define from separate line, e.g. `-----` or something like that, then look for that when you read the file.

Comment: In the case of MySQL, you could also set the connection property `allowMultiQueries=true` which allows you to execute multiple statements in one execute.